# Problema de conexion con servidor FreePBX y gateway grandstream!

Tags: linux, redes, centos7, asterisk

Que tal comunidad? Tengo un gateway grandstream gxw 4108 y un servidor Freepbx con Centos7 para telefonía IP, el problema es que se pierde la conexión entre el servidor y el gateway, es decir, reiniciando el servidor y haciendo un ping al gateway hay conexión, el problema es que pasado un tiempo, el gateway es inalcanzable por el servidor, ahora si yo hago un ping al gateway desde cualquier otro dispositivo en la red, llego sin problemas, y desde el servidor a cualquier otro dispositivo, también llegó sin problemas y viceversa.
El gw y el servidor se encuentran en el mismo espacio de direcciones, incluso mirando la tabla ARP en el servidor se ve que la dirección ip del gw está presente, pero no se cual es la raíz del problema, si alguien tiene una idea de que puede ser el causante del problema, le agradecería su colaboración.
NOTA: este gw se había reemplazado por uno mas nuevo y se dejó en caso de que el actual fallara, el único inconveniente que presenta es que tiene un puerto FXO quemado, pero en su momento esto no afectó su funcionamiento, se puso de nuevo en producción por que se quemó el actual, que no pierda la conexión con el servidor, en cambio este ya se reinicio y se configuró, pero presenta este problema de desconexión.

Comment: alguna novedad? sigue igual? Necesito mas datos/acontecimientos para ayudarte.

Comment: Que tal? problema solucionado, era problema del aparato, se puso uno nuevo y todo ok, gracias por contestar.